# writing to and reading from a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I was trying to code a list of students with some data on them into binary and decoding it to check if everything was coded fine, using as few bits as possible (e.g. 8 faculties → 3 bits). Coding into binary seems to work fine, but decoding it back doesn't.
I have 3 files in total:
original data - a list of data on students
binary code - consist of one line of coded information with no spaces
output check file

I tried using file pointers to head back to the beginning of the second file to read it propperly using seekp(), closing and opening file anew but id didn't seem to work for me.
Code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

struct Student {
    int faculty;//3bit
    int course;//3bit
    int group;//7
    std::string name;
};

void StringToUpperCase(std::string& str, int strlen) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
}

void code(unsigned char* c, int size, std::fstream & file){
    unsigned char uc;
    unsigned char m;
    uc = *c;
    for (int i = size - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        m = 1 << i;
        file << (((uc & m) != 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}

void decode(int size, std::fstream& input, std::ofstream& output) {
    int result = -1;
    int digit;
    for (int i = size - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        input >> digit;
        if (digit == 1) {
            result += pow(2, i);
        }
    }
    result += 1;
    output << result << " ";
}


void codeChar(unsigned char* c, std::fstream& file) {
    unsigned char uc;
    unsigned char m;
    if ((unsigned char)c == ' ') {
        uc = 27;
    }else{ uc = *c - 'A' + 1; }

    for (int i = 4; i > -1; i--) {
        m = 1 << i;
        file << (((uc & m) != 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}

void decodeChar(std::fstream& input, std::ofstream& output) {
    char symbol;
    int code = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i > -1; i--) {
        input >> symbol;
        if (symbol == '0') { code += pow(2, i); }
    }
    if (code == 27) {
        output << " ";
    }
    else { output << char(code + 'A' - 1); }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("D:\\cpp\\test.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "no file found";
        return 1;
    }
    int students_count;
    file >> students_count;
    int total_bytes = 0;
    
    Student line;

    std::fstream bitwise("D:\\cpp\\mid_product.txt", std::ios::app);
    std::ofstream result("D:\\cpp\\result.txt", std::ios::app);



    for (int i = 0; i < students_count; i++) {
        
        file >> line.faculty >> line.course >> line.group;
        line.faculty -= 1;
        std::getline(file, line.name, '\n');
        
        line.name = line.name.substr(1);
        
        int name_length = line.name.length();
        total_bytes += 13 + name_length*5;
        
        StringToUpperCase(line.name, name_length);

        code((unsigned char *)&line.faculty, 3, bitwise);
        code((unsigned char *)&line.course, 3, bitwise);
        code((unsigned char *)&line.group, 7, bitwise);
        for (int k = 0; k < name_length; k++) {
            codeChar((unsigned char*)&line.name[k], bitwise);
        }


        decode(3, bitwise, result);
        decode(3, bitwise, result);
        decode(7, bitwise, result);
        for (int j = 0; j < name_length; j++) {
            decodeChar(bitwise, result);
        }
        result << "\n";

    }

    result.close();
    file.close();
    
    
    total_bytes = (total_bytes / 8 >=1) ? (total_bytes / 8 + 1) : total_bytes;

}
```

some lines are excluded for the sake of space economy, and some may represent a complete gibberish as I was trying to to fix it many times.

putting in a file with one line:
`3 6 19 John Doe`
I am expecting to get a result in a third file:
`3 6 9 JOHN DOE`
but actual output is
`0 0 0 ________`
please help me make out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what do you mean that you are writing binary? You show ascii text as input

Comment: @pm100 I am entering ascii symbols via first file, rewriting in binary to second file, and reading from second file to decode it just to check. Sorry if I confused any terms.

Comment: It appears that you are writing a TEXT file, with the characters `1` or `0` for each bit - was that your goal?

Comment: May I ask _why_ you're taking such a convoluted approach to storing your data?

Comment: Suggestion: Do not do `int name_length = line.name.length();` and then provide that as a parameter to `StringToUpperCase`. Since you send in a reference to the `std::string`, why not call `length()` inside the function instead? You could also skip checking `length()` completely by using a range based for-loop instead.

Comment: @cucurbita *Coding into binary seems to work fine, but decoding it back doesn't.* -- Given your code, does this have anything to do with file reading/writing?  Isn't this just the testing of the `code` and `decode` functions to make sure they work, regardless of what is going on with the file code?  If so, then you should have tested `code` and `decode` using hardcoded data to make sure they work properly.

Comment: How did you get this to compile? I tried it with g++ and got an error on line 49, where you cast a pointer wrong: `if ((unsigned char)c == ' ')    cast from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char’ loses precision`

Comment: `pow(2, i)` does not do what you think it does. For example, `pow(2, 2)` may not necessarily be 4.

Comment: Unrelated: You should also check `if(bitwise)` and `if(result)`.

Comment: @paddy this is a task for my laboratoray work in University.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't really get it. Inside what function you're suggesting me to use length() and what for? Length of string is required to calculate total value of information to write to a resulting file, so I don't think I can refuse using it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the task is exactly about reading from one file, writing read information to the second file in way of ones and zeroes, reading from second file decoding its content to write to the third file.

Comment: @NickReed I straight up copy-pasted from my VS solution. No idea why does it not compile for you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this doesn't have my problem solved though. At the stage of debugging, it shows that variables "digit" and "symbol" always take the value of 0 in functions decode() and decodeChar().

Comment: @Jason in this case we're guaranteed to have these files not empty, so if the coding operation is correct, "bitwise" shouldn't be empty in ane scenario. Using if(result) isn't required, I think, because  I'm not trying to read from it.

Comment: @cucurbita I see, as long as you're aware of it.

Comment: @cucurbita _"Inside what function you're suggesting me to use length() and what for?"_ - Inside `StringToUpperCase` (as I wrote): [example](https://godbolt.org/z/871qr8scb). And yes, you can even do the transformation into uppercase without the length: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/PGx51cbon)

Comment: @TedLyngmo good thing I can do it, but still I need to store string length value to calculate information volume.

Comment: @cucurbita The point is that you do not need to send it in as an extra parameter to `StringToUpperCase`.